# Is there a performance difference in using $(window).width() and window.innerWidth?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

If I'm already using jQuery in my app, but want to improve performance as much as I can. Does it improve performance any to use vanilla JS instead of jQuery (for example) for getting window width in some places of my code?

Comment: Any use of vanilla js over jQuery would eliminate the jQuery over head of creating the jQuery objects.  Whither there is a noticable performance difference or not, I would guess no, however that would be up to you to perform a time trial to determine the improvement.

Comment: `window.innerWidth` will be faster then `$(window).width()`, but whether it lies in a noticeable and also important range is doubtful. And if is, then you might have a problem somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a huge performance difference! I tried it out in jsPerf: https://jsperf.com/window-width-jquery-vs-vanilla/1

Vanilla trumps jQuery!

There is of course notable overhead when you have to instantiate a new jQuery object (`$(window)`). If you must use jQuery, save the window jQuery object to a variable.

Comment: Define huge?  I see the test says that the jquery method is 94% slower.  But if that is 94% of single or double milliseconds ...  Also most webpages are not going to execute calls like that that many times.  It's interesting to see things like this in a vaccum, but it does not always relate directly to a real live implementation on a website.

Comment: 2ms is still double that of 1ms. To be a realist; no the performance is probably not gonna be notable - yet it totally depends on the use case. Listening to scroll or mousemove events? Then the code is gonna be fired often, and any shaved milliseconds is more time to do style recalculations and paint.

Comment: That's my point though.  Time trials are more relevant towards applications, rather than methods in a vaccum.  That's all I was getting at.

Answer (score 0):

There is always a performance price for using JQuery instead of plain (vanilla) JavaScript, since it is a library built on top of JavaScript to address browser native DOM API inconsistencies and make iteration over elements simpler (to name a few things).

Some examples of when to use JQuery:

- Tedious cross browser situations (for example AJAX)
- To facilitate chaining, simplify working on groups of elements together.

An exapmle of when not to use JQuery:

When executing a loop many times.

Unwrap all tags of a certain type. JQuery is simple but doesn't perform well when there are MANY elements to iterate over:

```
$('span').unwrap();  // unwrap all span elements
```

The native DOM API will perform better:

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

while( spans[0] ) {
    var parent = spans[0].parentNode;
    while( spans[0].firstChild ) {
        parent.insertBefore( spans[0].firstChild, spans[0]);
    }
    parent.removeChild( spans[0] );
}
```

> - window.innerWidth: with scrollbar
> - $(window).innerWidth(): wrong usage
> - $(window).width(): without scrollbar
> - mediaquery: with scrollbar (at least the standard ones)
>
> $(window).innerWidth(): this is actually a wrong way to get the inner
>   width of window, because api.jquery.com/innerWidth states that “This
>   method is not applicable to window and document objects; for these,
>   use .width() instead.”
>
> But what if we just need the inner width of window? We might need to
>   adjust images according to width. In this case, use window.innerWidth.
>
> window.innerWidth: quite literally, the width of window WITH scroll
>   bar (as all mediaquery should behave). But sadly, IE8 doesn’t support
>   it.
>
> So use:
>
> ```
> var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
> ```
>
> To be clear, window.innerWidth is different from the latter two since
>   only window.innerWidth includes scrollbar. But we don’t need to worry
>   about getting the wrong width in IE8 because it doesn’t support
>   Mediaquery–if it wants the width, it’ll have to resort to javascript
>   solutions anyway.

Source: http://luxiyalu.com/window-innerwidth-vs-window-innerwidth/